# To post a YouTube comment using a third-party application can the Oauth access be limited to just comments?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

For a CRM tool I need to use Comments: insert method of YouTube data v3 api.

The oAuth scope defined is

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl

This is wide scope allowing the app to also manipulate video and delete data.

Is there a way to limit the scope to just comments?

Answer (score 0):

if you check the documentation page for [comments insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert) method you will find it states

[image]

This is the only acceptable scope to gain access to insert comments.  Your only option to limit the use of this scope, would be to not insert comments then you wouldn't need this scope.